# Pandas dataframe sorting string values and by descending aggregated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I'm working on transforming a dataframe to show the top 3 earners.

The dataframe looks like this

```
data = {'Name': ['Allistair', 'Bob', 'Carrie', 'Diane', 'Allistair', 'Bob', 'Carrie','Evelyn'], 'Sale': [20, 21, 19, 18, 5, 300, 35, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

     Name  Sale
0  Allistair    20
1        Bob    21
2     Carrie    19
3      Diane    18
4  Allistair     5
5        Bob   300
6     Carrie    35
7     Evelyn    22
```

In my actual dataset, I have several more columns and rows, and I want to print out and get to

something like

```
   Name  Sale
0        Bob   321
1     Carrie    35
2  Allistair    25
```

Every iteration that I've searched through doesn't quite get there because I get

```
'Name' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.
```

Comment: Do you want something like this: `df.groupby("Name")["Sale"].sum().nlargest(3)` ?

Comment: That's exactly it! I worked on thi for awhile, and it seems so simple now. (I kept getting an error about "Name" being an index and a column and it being ambiguous.) Thank you! I'll add it as the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Name').sum().sort_values('Sale', ascending=False)
           Sale
Name
Bob         321
Carrie       54
Allistair    25
Evelyn       22
Diane        18
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andrej Kasely above,

```
df.groupby("Name")["Sale"].sum().nlargest(3)
```